# Story about a mage in a setting where the land area of person's spirit realm dictates their strength

Tags: story-identification, cultivation

Some time ago, I read most of a cultivation series about a kid who is raised in "the Forest of Black and White" in a fortress and away from basically everybody except his dad, who was secretly super-wealthy.

Early in the story, he walks to civilization, goes to bank and comes to get his inheritance. There he meets a women who later becomes his wife. He also ends up having some kind of vaguely-consensual relationship with a water elemental.

He becomes a mage, and in this setting, mages increase their power by slowly growing the total land area of their mental/spiritual realm that only they can access. He ends up somehow familiar-bonded to a fire demon and has to keep that quiet.

The last thing I recall from the series is that his entire world is just the surface of some kind of shard floating through space and that he's the last descendent of some super-powerful eagle being, but also that eagle's nemesis, an astral dragon?

In spite of these details, I can't seem to find the book/series in question. ChatGPT seems to think that it's called "Soul Land" AKA "Douluo Dalu" by Tang Jia San Shao, but if so, the version I read was in English and had minimal "cheaply translated Chinese novel" flavor to it.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a search engine, and you should not trust it to tell you information about obscure things. For instance, it happily tells me that "*Telling New Mexico: A New History* was written by F. Chris Garcia." He didn't write it, edit it, or contribute a chapter, but he *was* the president of the University of New Mexico for a whole year, and the book was published by the University of New Mexico Press a decade later, so....

Comment: @Adamant - I'm aware of the limitations, but it's often proved useful for situations where you can describe a thing but don't know what it's called.

Comment: Sometimes. But in the end it is a language model, not an ontological inference engine, to say nothing of a person, so it is only as good as other people have described the same thing in similar words in its training data, and it easily makes mistakes when something else is described in similar words. Does [this](https://soulland.fandom.com/wiki/Tang_San) look like what you have described? That is a description of the protagonist of *Soul Land*.

Comment: @Adamant I know 100% that this is not Soul Land because I am a fan of Soul Land. Tang San never had to escape from his dad, and there is no mention of a "Forest of Black and White" anywhere in Soul Land.

Comment: @Silvermidnight - I didn't think so. -1 for ChatGPT.

Comment: About the "minimal cheaply translated Chinese novel flavor". Do you remember if this book Chinese or not? For example, most Chinese books translated into English have a reoccurring "gongzi" aka. "childe" appearing in them. Another one would be "lao shi" aka. "teacher/master".

Comment: @Adamant - I basically never trust ChatGPT on its own since it can be so very convincingly wrong... hence this question!

Comment: @Silvermidnight - I *think* it had concept and skill/attack names that sounded like they were probably originally in Chinese or were supposed to invoke that flavor. A few too many references to "heavenly", "dragon", "ultimate", and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be "[The Storm King](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/16476/the-storm-king)" by Warden1207, also published on http://wardenreading.com (I assume the URL works. I'm on a work computer, and they consider that site to be entertainment, so I can't see it).

> Leon and his father, Artorias, are the last remaining scions of a once powerful and illustrious family of lightning mages.  After barely surviving an attack that destroyed their home fifteen years ago, they now live in the dangerous Northern Vales, a desolate wilderness far away from civilization.  But those who want them dead are strong, patient, and relentless, and it is only a matter of time before they find the two they seek...

It involves a boy and his father in a compound in a vale of "The Forest of Black and White" where they build their physical prowess as mages by breathing in the magic and letting it seep into their body. Three chapters in, they haven't traveled into town yet, but I have seen some reviews mentioning that the Spirit Realm becomes important.

Here's an excerpt from the first chapter:

> One of those places was the Forest of Black and White, which took up the entirety of one of the smaller vales.  No tribe had ever lived there, and few even dared to approach the mountain passes that led to it.  It was a place of horror, of terrifying bedtime stories told to the children of the tribes.  If they were not brave against their enemies and true to their friends, the wraiths and evil gods of the forest would come to take them in the night.
>
> The vale was one hundred miles east to west and seventy miles north to south, and the Forest of Black and White covered almost the entirety of that land.  The forest received its name from the trees of dark bark and brilliant green leaves, and the trees of pale white bark and deep, twilight blue leaves that are most commonly seen within it.
>
> Many strange and otherworldly beings called the forest home, from the vicious beasts of flesh and blood to the spirits of ice, earth, and wind.  But perhaps the strangest beings that lived in this forest were two men, a father and son pair, who built their home deep within the eastern reaches of the forest in a large clearing of purple grass.
>
> The father was tall, well-built, and looked roughly in his mid-twenties—though he was at least a decade older than that.  He had black hair, warm brown eyes, sharp features, and a straight nose.  The son was a youth of sixteen, slightly shorter than his father and with a skinnier build.  His features took after his father for the most part, except for his bright golden eyes.
>
> The son, Leon, was dressed in a loose-fitting shirt made of dark green woven grass—a specialty of the nearest tribe—with brown leather pants and boots.  He had a hunting bow slung over his shoulder, a quiver full of arrows on his back, and a knife at his leather belt.  His father, Artorias, was largely dressed the same, save for a light brown fur coat and a longsword at his hip.

Found with a search for `wuxia "forest of black and white"`

Comment: Thanks! But also: guh! I searched for `cultivation "forest of black and white"` and a number of similar attempts and didn't catch any mentions of "storm" that would've pulled me closer to an answer. `the` seems to be the key word there, surprisingly, as it determines whether you get there or not. Great work!

Comment: This question is now in the top five for searches including "forest of black and white", so hopefully it'll help the next person, too.

Comment: I, too, started out by using the term cultivation. I used the wuxia term instead, because I was getting too many results for farming. :-)